# Facebook API 3.0.1, How to Delete Notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to get all Notifications from a User. This works fine.
Now i want to process the Notifications in a loop and delete them, when processing is finished.

I copy/pasted this code from the Facebook Developer Website

```
private void deleteRequest(String inRequestId) {
// Create a new request for an HTTP delete with the
// request ID as the Graph path.
Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), 
    inRequestId, null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // Show a confirmation of the deletion
            // when the API call completes successfully.
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Request deleted",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
// Execute the request asynchronously.
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

When executed, i get the error message: **Unsupported delete request**

My inRequestId parameter looks like this: '**notif_670328449_186512168**'

I already tryed the same request without the "**notif_**" part... but also not working.

My Question is, what is the correct Notification Request ID?
How can i delete Notifications, after i processed them?

Info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/app-link-requests/#step2